# What does this だけ mean in particular?

Tags: grammar, words

I read the definition of くだら◦ない【下らない】:

> ［連語］《動詞「くだる」の未然形＋打消しの助動詞「ない」》まじめに取り合う**だけ**の価値がない。

I know everything but that だけ. I've searched it up but I have no clue "which" だけ is used here.

Comment: The second definition in this [wiktionary entry](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91): 分量・限度・程度を表す。「～ほど」、「～くらい」、「～かぎり」。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am going to plagiarize my own answer here.:

[Understanding the だけ in this context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92942/30454)

I am not suggesting it as a duplicate because I will explain your phrase at the end.

Broadly speaking most of だけ's usages fall under two general categories: a negative sense and a positive one. I think because the negative sense is taught earlier to us Japanese learners, most people are more familiar with that sense. But the other meaning is also very common and unfortunately easily confusable with the negative sense.

The negative sense functions to limit a degree, scope, or reference, and is explained as:

> 1. 範囲を限定することを表す。「～ばかり」、「～のみ」。([Wiktionary Japanese](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91))
>    in a negative, limiting sense: only, just, limit ([Wiktionary English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91))

But here the other sense is invoked in your text:

> 2. 分量・限度・程度を表す。「～ほど」、「～くらい」、「～かぎり」。
>    in a positive, non-limiting sense: amount, as much as

As explained in that Wiktionary entry:

> ある程度は肯定的に評価できることを表す。
>
> - おんぼろの中古車だが、走るだけましかな。
> - タイムはともかく、この悪天候下で完走しただけ立派だ。

So given that this is "as much as", 「ほど」 and 「くらい」 are synonyms that might be of help. まじめに取り合うだけの価値 means "as much value as being seriously considered"

まじめに取り合うだけの価値がない: not worthy of being seriously considered/not worthy of serious consideration/attention

Comment: Do native speakers actually think of these as different senses? I've noticed a pattern with JP-EN dictionaries where a conjunction or expression will be given two opposite glosses, and then you read the fine print and see that one of them is specifically applicable in a negative context (like with e.g. しかない). With だけ, it seems like either way the core underlying idea is "this is the amount to which <main clause>".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think that's a really interesting point, and to get an answer to that we'd have to ask native speakers, preferably not just one but survey a sample pool of native speakers. That's something I also wondered with [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92953/30454). My best conjecture based on my observation and reflection on English words would be: for native speakers the degree varies from word to word. There are words that even native speakers see as having multiple distinct usages (positive/negative), but for some others no clear line exists in the native mind.

Comment: The meaning of だけ is determined by what follows it because that’s where we can infer whether the speaker sees the amount positively or negatively. I personally don’t see it as having two different meanings in itself.

Comment: As for 惜しい, the two definitions can be understood as referring to your feeling towards the difference between (1) what you already have and what you might end up having, or (2) what you ended up having and what you hoped to have. Only the second sense is possible in the context of the linked question because no one is going to lose anything there. It is just that “regrettable” is probably too strong a word to describe the speaker’s feeling in that situation, making “close” a more appropriate translation. It is highly context-dependent and rather subjective.

Comment: @aguijonazo Very helpful explanations! Thank you. I understand だけ being determined by what follows and 惜しい being vague, but 惜しい's distinction between 1 and 2 still feels elusive to me. This example sentence 終わってしまうのは本当に惜しい comes under Wiktionary's "regrettable" entry. So the thing having ended is what we have, and it being still ongoing is what we might end up having? But isn't that what we hope to have? (wait if I were to use 惜しい to describe the current situation of me understanding the gist of your explanations, but have yet to grasp some points, is that "regrettable" or "close"?)

Comment: When you say 終わってしまうのは惜しい, whatever you refer to is still ongoing. When it ends, it creates a difference towards which you know you are going to have a certain feeling. It falls in the first category. In English you might describe this feeling with the verb “to miss.” My English dictionary gives the following definition for this sense of “miss”: *feel regret or sadness at no longer being able to enjoy the presence of.* If you are asked to give an adjective-to-adjective translation to express the same idea, you might choose to say “*regrettable*.” I guess that’s what bilingual dictionaries do.

Comment: @aguijonazo I feel I'm not quite there yet, but definitely getting closer with each new comment from you. This point is well taken: "I miss my friend." = "It's regrettable my friend is not here with me." So the first category seems close to 勿体ない?

Comment: Indeed, もったいない and 惜しい are sometimes interchangeable. In fact, you could say 終わってしまうのはもったいない in your example. But it has a connotation that you think whatever is ongoing deserves to be continued and see its ending as a waste. In general terms, you regret a situation where something you think is valuable is not fully utilized. もったいない could sound rude if used for a person. You can say 惜しい人を亡くした when someone has died, but if you said もったいない人を亡くした, you would sound like you were seeing that person only as a convenient resource or something.